# microk8s installation : version `GLIBC_2.27' not found

Tags: 20.04, microk8s

I tried to install microk8s on my ubuntu 20.04, but when I check for the status `microk8s status` I got this error

```
/snap/microk8s/1839/bin/uname: /snap/core/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4l2.so.0)
/snap/microk8s/1839/bin/uname: /snap/core/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4lconvert.so.0)
```

My LDD version

```
> ldd --version
ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.31-0ubuntu9.1) 2.31
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.
```

*EDIT*

I do not have this error when running with sudo

```
> sudo microk8s status
```

However, the user is well in the `microk8s` group.